# All pages showing up as homepage on Wordpress website

Tags: redirect, homepage, blog

Why would this be happening? Every link I click on on my site results in the homepage again. You can check it out here: http://www.whatamidoingonline.com

What is going on here? This just started all of a sudden this morning. I have tried deactivating all plugins (changing plugin directory name), tried publishing new posts and pages, etc..

The problem was caused by a plugin that was supposed to fix a permalink problem, so I deactivated the plugin and the old problem still persisted. Go to my site and click on any of the blog posts, you'll see they result in a 404 error. When I first saw this, I tried yout method. I changed the permalink structure and they worked! but changing them back broke them again. I can't change the permalink structure permanently because of link building and social media stuff I have already done.

Comment: Things don't just start misbehaving "all of a sudden", despite how it may appear. Almost certainly, somebody did something to trigger this. If you honestly haven't done anything, check with your host to see if they updated the server or altered configuration-- something like that.

Comment: What I meant, is I can't figure out what could have triggered it. I've retraced my steps since the last time I could confirm it was working properly

Comment: [Troubleshoot](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-35-master-list) and [debug](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress) the site. As it is, this is not a real Question... voting to close too.

Answer (score 3):

I have seen this before. It was caused by a permalink saving error, in my case.

Go to Settings >> Permalinks.

Select a different permalink option than the one you're currently using. Click "Save Changes"

Select the permalink structure you want to use. Click "Save Changes"

That fixed it when I encountered the same situation.

Comment: Thanks, Actually the problem was caused by a plugin that was supposed to fix a permalink problem, so I deactivated the plugin and the old problem still persisted. Go to my site and click on any of the blog posts, you'll see they result in a 404 error. When I first saw this, I tried yout method. I changed the permalink structure and they worked! but changing them back broke them again. I can't change the permalink structure permanently because of link building and social media stuff I have already done. Any other solutions?

Comment: @Christian: most everything in this comment belongs in your Question, please edit it to show what you've tried to do to fix the problem, and include what permalink structure you're having problems with, since that seems the root cause of your problem.

Answer (score 2):

When your adding a new page, in the settings of the page when your editing it - under 'Template' make sure you change it from default to page(no seperators). This Worked for me.